# Comparing newline doesn't work properly

Tags: c, if-statement

I have the following code in C to make an input file using an existing input file, but without  newlines:

```
int main()
{
    int T;
    char c;
    FILE *fi,*fo;
    fi=fopen("Square-practice.in","r");
    fo=fopen("Square-practice-a.in","w");

    fscanf(fi,"%d",&T);
    fprintf(fo,"%d",T);
    while(fscanf(fi,"%c",&c)==1){
        if(c=='\n') printf("qwert");
        else    fprintf(fo,"%c",c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There is no compiling error.

However, the output file is exactly the same as the input file, with the newline included.
"qwert" is printed 8 times (same as the number of newlines in file fi). So why doesn't the "else" work?

The compiler is MinGW.

Both the fi,fo files are [here](http://www.filedropper.com/cj)

Comment: fgetc() also results in the same output.

Comment: Check my answer. Does it work on your compiler?

Comment: @user117913 - regarding fgetc(), it will work if it is coded right.  See below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm running this on my Linux and I'm getting just what I should be getting: the same file without new line characters and `"qwert"` printed to stdout. If you're getting something else, it must be an issue with CR/LF translation. Try replacing `"r"` and `"w"` with `"rt"` and `"wt"`, respectively.

---

Two PS comments:

1. The given program works (with or without `"rt"`) on my `gcc` 4.7.2 on Linux, provided that line terminators in the input file are converted from CRLF to LF.  This is reasonable when you move a text file from Windows to Linux and can be done, e.g., with the `fromdos` tool.
2. It is true that the C standard (section 7.19.5.3, p. 271, for [ISO C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), or section 7.21.5.3, p. 306, for [ISO C2011](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) does not require `"t"` for text files (so, conforming implementations need not implement it), but it seems that some implementations work differently.

Comment: I am using Linux. Where did you compiler?

Comment: Linux, also...  The original file has CRLF terminators (probably comes from Windows).  If you move it to Linux, even in text mode, the CR will be left untouched.  This is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have '\r\n' instead of '\n'. So try

```
int main()
{
    int T;
    char c;
    FILE *fi,*fo;
    fi=fopen("Square-practice.in","r");
    fo=fopen("Square-practice-a.in","w");

    fscanf(fi,"%d",&T);
    fprintf(fo,"%d",T);
    while(fscanf(fi,"%c",&c)==1){
        if(c=='\n' || c=='\r') printf("qwert");
        else    fprintf(fo,"%c",c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `fgetc()` and `fputc()`.  Just skip any `\r` or `\n` before passing each char into new file:

Your code with modifications:

```
int main()
{

    int T;
    int iChr
    char c;
    FILE *fi,*fo;
    fi=fopen("Square-practice.in","r");
    fo=fopen("Square-practice-a.in","w");

    //fscanf(fi,"%d",&T);
    //fprintf(fo,"%d",T);
    iChr = fgetc(fi)
    while(iChr != EOF)
    {
        if((iChr =='\n')||(iChr =='\r')//skipping new file
        {
             printf("qwert");
        }
        else   fputc(fo);//no \n or \r, put in new file
    }
    fclose(fi);        
    fclose(fo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why checking for '\n' two times? anyway it is same answer as mine.

Comment: @TejasPatel- Lol.  Ooops, meant one of those to be a '\r'.  Nice catch.  (will edit)  +1 for yours.